# Hide multiple devices with same IP addresses behind multiple one to one NATs

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I have a couple of devices with the same unchangeable IP address. I would like to NAT these to addresses which I can then address individually.
eg,

```
eth0 = external network, 192.168.1.0/24
eth1 connected to host1, fixed ip = 10.1.1.2, NATted to 192.168.1.11
eth2 connected to host2, fixed ip = 10.1.1.2, NATted to 192.168.1.12
```

host1 and host2 don't need to talk to each other.

I'm trying to implement this on Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

I thought performing a nat POSTROUTING could do it, except iptables doesn't allow that.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: So you want the traffic from host1 and host2 to be NATed outbound when passing through eth1 and eth2 through eth0?

Comment: It might be possible to set up a tiny Raspberry PI in front of each such device as a NAT device that can be programmed to each device with the same IP address. I have not seen such a device but it may be possible.

Comment: @xtcn That right.

Comment: @John It would be possible, but I'm trying to use the 4 x 1Gb hardware I have

Comment: Most likely you can't do it with iptables / typical NAT. Rather try something like `ip daddr 192.168.1.11 ip daddr set 10.1.1.2` in nftables. You'll need to mark the traffics before that (or in the same rule) and set up policy route with `ip rule` as well. Only then traffics can be routed out of the interface that they should go respectively. The rule should probably be in a chain of type filter and priority raw. Not sure whether you should use the forward hook or prerouting hook though (maybe either is fine). You'll also need to ARP proxy for 192.168.1.{11,12}.

Comment: You also need something like `iifname eth1 ip saddr 10.1.1.2 ip saddr set 192.168.1.11` for the traffics other way round. Also, there's the bridge family in nftables. You might be able to make use of that to do it in a different approach if bridging all three eths is alright to you.

Comment: Do host1 and host2 have a default route? In which case through which gateway IP address? Else if there's no such default route, are they just in a /24 LAN without other route than the link route to this 10.1.1.0/24 ?

Comment: @A.B Yes they do have a default route: 10.1.1.1

Comment: @TomYan I'll take a look at nftables, something I have not done before.